# How to convert PB methd setNull into java equivalent using awk

Tags: awk

I´m trying to convert 
this sentence: `setNull( this.isEx.dif_A_B)` wich is a powerbuilder method into `this.isEx.dif_A_B = 0`
the equivalent in java.

I have tried to use gensub with the following regex:

```
line = gensub(/setNull[(][ \t]?(\w|\.)*[ \t]?[)]/, " \\1 = 0 " , "g", line);
```

but the output is B=0

I dont get it why he only catches the last letter.

How i can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `(\w|\.)*` is wrong, you meant `([\w.]*)`, or maybe even `([[:alnum:]_.]*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but is already solved,the asterisk is missing in front o "w".

```
linha =  gensub(/setNull\(( |\t)*(\w*|\.)*( |\t)*\)/, " \\2 = 0 " , "g", linha)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `(` or `)` or *space* as the field delimiter and then pick field 3:

```
awk -F'[() ]' '{printf "%s = 0\n", $3}' input.file
```